# when I run the program it tells me "NameError: name 'thread' is not defined" What should I do?

Tags: python, multithreading

•   Assume that you have an array (data=[]) containing 500,000 elements and that each element has been assigned a random value between 1 and 10 (random.randint(1,10)) .

for  i in range (500000):
    data[i]=random.randint()

•   Allow the users to determine the number of worker threads (N). The user can enter a value between 1 and 10. Invalid values should result in a warning message and the thread count being set to 5.
•   Work out a method of automatically partitioning the array into N equal segments, where N is the number of worker threads (threadCount). You cannot create subarrays to handle this problem; you must work out a method of partitioning the original array based on indices. A hint is provided below assuming that the user has entered a threadCount of 4.

Segment 1
(125,000 elements)  Segment 2
(125,000 elements)  Segment 3
(125,000 elements)  Segment 4
(125,000 elements)

•   Determine a method to spawn your threads so that each thread is assigned a segment of the array to operate on. These threads should create a sum of the elements for their allotted segment. The single threaded function prototype is given below:

def summation(st, end, threadIndex):

where: st and end represent the start and end points of the array segment, and index is the thread number.

Your must determine the locking mechanism to ensure the program can run concurrently on the array.

•   After each thread has completed its work the main program should compute the final average by summing the sub-sums and diving by the total number of array elements.

Final Exercise:
Can you extend your program so that the array is populated with random numbers using your worker threads?

My Code:

```
import random
import thread
def su(st,end,i):
    global subtotal, data, locks
    for index in range(st,end+i):
        subtotal[i] += data[index]
    lock.release()

numth = int(100)

data = list(range(numth))

for index in range(len(data)):
    data[index] = random.randint(1,10)

wt=int(input("enter"))

locks = list(range(wt))

subtotal = list(range(wt))

seg = len(data)/wt

st=0

for i in range(wt):
    st= i * seg
    end = st *seg -1
    thread.start_new_thread(su, ())
    locks=lock.acquire()
avg = sum(subtotal)/len(data)

print(avg)
```

Comment: You should listen to the error message.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do not just tag your question with every popular tag you can think of. This is a Python question, use *just* the Python tag. You didn't tell us much about the error in your post either, you could have done with a sentence.

Comment: Sorry for that,,, this is my first question here

Answer (score 2):

You are importing `_thread` instead of `thread`, remove the underscore. Remove the underscore from the `_thread.start_new_thread()` line too.

In general, do not use modules that start with an underscore, they are an internal implementation detail.

Comment: Sorry for that, this is my first question here :) I removed it and it still prompting me with the same mistake

Comment: So you now have `import thread` and use *only* `thread` throughout your code?

Comment: yes! I did that Now it is telling me:                                         locks[i]=thread.allocate_locks()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'allocate_locks'

Comment: Remove the `s` at the end, it is `allocate_lock`, singular. Do verify that you spell things correctly, check the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html) for example.

Comment: I did it ! now I changed numth variable to 100 and when I press run it does not show anything

Comment: Take a good look at how you are handling locks; you only have *one*, not a list.

Comment: Also, you want to acquire that one lock *in the thread*, not before starting the thread.

Comment: This is my code now mate:                                                      for i in range(wt):
    st= i * seg
    end = st *seg -1
    thread.start_new_thread(su, st,end,i)
    locks=lock.acquire()
    locks[i]=thread.allocate_lock()                                          It keeps giving me error : it tells me name lock is not defined

Comment: I will update the code, thanks mate for the help, it gives still errors

Comment: Sorry, Stack Overflow is not an interactive debugging session. Can you please ask separate questions for new issues?

Comment: Yes, here it is...:                                                                     [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200549/when-i-run-it-tells-me-this-nameerror-name-lock-is-not-defined)